# Редактор и руководство по Ruby on Rails на Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой редактор использовать? И вообще с чего лучше начать, два года я сидел на php, хочу узнать руби. Есть ли какое нибудь пособие для руби на форточках?

Comment: Ruby и Rails, кроссплатформенные, пособия для всех систем одни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень хороший редактор, вполне способный заменить маковский TextMate - это Sublime Text 2, попробуйте его.
Почитать можете действительно Фултона, но по ходу дела обязательно обратите внимание на Ruby Koans, может помочь в понимании принципов языка.

Answer (score 1):

Редакторы:

- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)
- [RedCar](http://redcareditor.com/)
- [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/)
- [Aptana RadRails](http://www.aptana.com/)
- [Ruby In Steel](http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Products/Ruby-In-Steel/Ruby-In-Steel-Developer-Overview)

Руководства:

- Программирование на языке Руби, Хэл Фултон.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ отличная замена блокноту.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте IDE, а не редактор. Хороший IDE можно назвать RubyMine. Только вот придется закупить его (я брал зимой по акции за $49).

Comment: Для не огромных проектов можно, по-моему, и хорошим редактором обойтись.